# How can I integrate my VB6 code with the WhatsApp API to send messages and attachments?

Tags: vb6

I hope to integrate my vb6 code with WhatsApp API to only send message and may be attachment file

when try tis code nothing at all and no message sent

```
x = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "Open", "whatsapp://send?phone=+21005145232&text=hello!", "", "", SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
MsgBox x
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code. What type of variable is `x`?  What is the value of `x` after the call?  How is `ShellExecute` declared?